# Chained tokens for referenced custom entities

Tags: entities, tokens, 9

We have two custom entities: *parliament_period* (can be an election or a legislature) and *parliament*. A *parliament_period* entity has a reference to a *parliament* entity.
In a *Poll* node, we have an entity reference field for *parliament_period* entities whose bundle is *legislature* (*field_legislature*). (It is about polls the deputies take part of.)
Part of the path alias for *Poll* nodes should be the content of a *url_basis* field from the *parliament* entities.

I used *[node:field_legislature:entity:parliament:entity:url_basis]/[node:field_legislature:entity:identifier]/poll/[node:title]* as Pathauto pattern. It used to work for some time, but it stopped working because of the *[node:field_legislature:entity:parliament:entity:url_basis]* token.

I am not sure what I have changed to make it stop working. In the `hook_tokens()` implementation I used the following code.

```php
if ($type == 'parliament_period' && !empty($data['parliament_period'])) {
  /** @var \Drupal\pw_basic\Entity\ParliamentPeriod $parliamentPeriod */
  $parliamentPeriod = $data['parliament_period'];
  if ($parliament_tokens = $token_service->findWithPrefix($tokens, 'parliament')) {
    $replacements += $token_service->generate('parliament', $parliament_tokens, ['parliament' => $parliamentPeriod->getParliament()], $options, $bubbleable_metadata);
  }
}
```

This allows for chaining to replace any tokens related to a *parliament* entity when a *parliament_period* entity is given (such as in *[node:field_legislature:entity]*). `hook_tokens()` is correctly invoked for the *parliament* entity tokens, but the name of the token sent to `hook_tokens()` is *entity:url_basis*, not *url_basis*.

On the other hand, *[node:field_legislature:entity:parliament:url_basis]* is not allowed, without the *entity* part.

Should I remove the *entity:* part before I call `$token_service->generate()`for all the tokens identified, or is there a better way to chain tokens for custom entities?

Comment: *entity* should not be removed. It's the code handling the tokens for the *parliament* entity that needs to handle it, not the code handling tokens for the *parliament_period* entity. We cannot tell you why the code worked before and it's not working now, without seeing the code you used before and the code you use now. We would also need to see the full `hook_tokens()` code, not just a few lines.

Comment: Also, was the Token module or another module that implements tokens uninstalled before the code stopped to work, or installed?

Comment: I'm wondering why you need a custom token for this at all? Assuming `parliament` is the name of an entity reference field on the `parliament_period` entity type, `[node:field_legislature:entity:parliament:entity:url_basis]` would already be available without any extra code

Comment: @Clive This assumption is correct: `parliament` here in this token is a field name in `parliament_period' entity which references a parliament entity.  So you mean this should already work? It did work as I mentioned and I did not find any changes so I got confused a) why it worked and b) why now it does not work anymore. Can you tell me where the Token module handles this chaining?

Comment: token.tokens.inc > [`field_tokens()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/token/-/blob/8.x-1.x/token.tokens.inc#L1677) - "Implements hook_tokens() on behalf of field.module."

Comment: Thank you @4k4 - I actually found the place why the chaining is not working anymore. I opened an issue in the project page on drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/project/token/issues/3228947